# Nginx location directive with regular expression to extract folder name and using in try_files

Tags: nginx, restful-url

I'm currently using the following location directive along with the try_files for a restfull application:

```
location /branches/branchx/app/api/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /branches/branchx/app/api/api.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Where `branchx` is the name of my Git branch. I may therefore have multiple branches such as: `branch1`, `branch2`, etc..

And therefore I need to manually create a directive for each and every branches I will create.

To avoid this issue, I'm looking to **use a regular expression to extract the branch name and using it in my try_files directive.** So I'd have a dynamic system managed by a single location directive taking care of all branches.

All attempts to use a regex so far in the try_files end up by throwing a 405 or 404 error.

My last attempt (based on @Richard Smith answer):

```
location ~ ^(/branches/[^/]+/app/api)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $1/api.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Which returned a 405 (Not Allowed) response for matching uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a regular expression `location`, you can capture the path at the same time. For example:

```
location ~ ^(/branches/[^/]+/app/api)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $1/api.php$is_args$args;
}
```

**Important note:** Changing from a prefix `location` to a regular expression `location` will change the evaluation order. Regular expression `location` blocks are evaluated in order, so `/branches/branchx/app/api/api.php` will match this `location` block **unless** it is placed after the `location ~ \.php$` location block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work for me. As I have one more subfolder that I didn't put in the example for simplification: `/branches/branch1/app/api/` I adapted your example with `~ ^(/branches/[^/]+/app/api)/` and the try_files with `$1/app/api.php`. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are a number of options, but without seeing the problem it is difficult to make specific suggestions. You should consider editing your question and improving your example.

Comment: That's done I clarified the question. Concerning the location, I just added `app` sub-folder.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you original comment. I thought your edits would be more extensive. I have added a note to the answer, I suspect you need to move the `location` block **below** the `location ~ \.php$` location block.

Comment: After moving the location block **below** the `location ~ \.php$` block, all worked well!