# NGINX - match all locations

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-location

I'm running a local development server using a LEMP stack. We want NGINX to serve multiple sites without having to manually put the location blocks in.

Desired results

http://localserver/site1/
http://localserver/site2/

Now, usually you would have to put location blocks in like below

```
location /site1 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /site1/index.php?args;
}

location /site2 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /site2/index.php?args;
}
```

Is there some kind of regex that can handle the sitename parts?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082425/regex-or-wildcard-for-subdirectories-in-an-nginx-location-directive/57082677#57082677 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44193158/nginx-location-directive-with-regular-expression-to-extract-folder-name-and-usin/44196028#44196028

Comment: Thank you so much. this one did it for me -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082425/regex-or-wildcard-for-subdirectories-in-an-nginx-location-directive/57082677#57082677